# document follow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

When i click follow in a document then i get this error

"To follow documents or sites, we need to get a couple of things set up. This can take a few minutes to complete, and once it's done, you'll need to come back to this site and try following again."

It shows an Option get started.when i start it,some process is running in the background and then document follow ir working. what is that process or any Service is started and how can it be done automatically ?.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you have mysites that are created using self service site creation so I think that SharePoint created a mysite for your account to track what you are following.

Comment: With the self service site creation is it not possible to create the personal site along with that ? We deploy mysite feature as wsp.